# Data Transfer between two forms in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

How to transfer data between two forms in orbeon ?

say for example I have form X with input control (say Name), Now i Want to get the value entered in another form Y. Is there any way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that the user might have filled out multiple "instances" of form *X*, where she provided her name. If she did, and entered different name, which one would you pick? We have a blog post that shows how to [show all the possible values in a dropdown](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/03/dropdown-populated-based-on-values-from.html).

But your requirement might be different. Also that post is written assuming your data is stored in eXist; this is the default, but you might of course instead be using a relational database. I hope the post will help, but if not, feel free to post another question, with your specific requirements.